# Controlar dos condiciones

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

```
do{
        var boolean = false;
        var numeros_entrats = prompt("Introduce cinco numeros");
        var res_numeros = numeros_entrats.split(" ");
        res_numeros = res_numeros.map(Number);
        console.log(res_numeros.length);
        for (var i = 0; res_numeros.length; i++){
            var tope = 50;
            if (tope < res_numeros[i])
            boolean = true;
        }
    }while(res_numeros.length != 5 && boolean);
```

Con este ejercicio lo que quiero es que el usuario solo pueda introducir cinco numeros, que eso me funciona, el problema viene, cuando a parte de eso, quiero que los numeros que tengo en el array `res_numeros` ninguno supere el 50.

Comment: `if (tope < res_numeros[i])`  esto está comprobando que los números sean MAYORES a 50, invierte las condiciones o usa `>`

Comment: Lo he probado pero no sale del bucle.

Comment: Claro que no sale del bucle, usaste un AND en el bucle, con lo cual hasta que ambas condiciones no se cumplan no va a salir. Tendrías que haber hecho `while(res_numeros.length != 5 || boolean);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hola albert mira podes usar el .some para barrer el array , el some devuelve true si hay algun elemento del array que  cumple con la  condicion que pases por la funcion implementada/callback , en este caso cada **el** representa un numero del array y la condicion pregunta si es mayor a 50 (el>50) si es asi el **do** se vuelve a ejecutar la otra parte de la comprobacion esta correcta (res_numeros.length!=5).Tambien podes concatenar el .map despues del split

```js
 do{
           
           var numeros_entrats = prompt("Introduce cinco numeros");
    
           var res_numeros = numeros_entrats.split(" ").map(Number);
            
           console.log(res_numeros.length);
         
       }while(res_numeros.some(el=>el>50)|| res_numeros.length!=5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Agrego correcciones enumeradas:

```js
do{
        var boolean = false;
        var numeros_entrats = prompt("Introduce cinco numeros");
        var res_numeros = numeros_entrats.split(" ");
        res_numeros = res_numeros.map(Number);
        console.log(res_numeros);
        
        // 1. Falta la condición de terminación del for
        for (var i = 0; i < res_numeros.length; i++){
            var tope = 50;
            
            if (tope < res_numeros[i])
              boolean = true;
        }
  // 2. Usar || en lugar de &&
 }while(res_numeros.length != 5 || boolean);
```